# php json_decode error quoted object property name expected

Tags: php, json

I try to create a script that decoding a simple `JSON` string in `PHP` and I get the following error:

`quoted object property name expected`

The string I try to decode is the following :

```
{"values":[{"url":"http://www.google.com","matches":"http|www|google|com"},{"url":"http://www.yahoo.com","matches":"http|www|yahoo|com"}]}
```

and the code I use to decoded is the following:

```
json_decode( $json_string );
```

I also have try to validate my json string in some online json validators, and the string seems to be fine.

Can someone please help me ?

Do you think the problem exists because of the double quotes ?

**Update #1**

Definetelly was a debuging issue. I place my experience here just to help other devs may come accross the same issue in the feature:

The problem was that my variable that came with the json string was html encoded so instead of the following string :

```
{"values":[{"url":"http://www.google.com","matches":"http|www|google|com"},{"url":"http://www.yahoo.com","matches":"http|www|yahoo|com"}]}
```

my variable came with the following string inside :

```
{&quot;values&quot;:[{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;http://www.google.com&quot;,&quot;matches&quot;:&quot;http|www|google|com&quot;},{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;http://www.yahoo.com&quot;,&quot;matches&quot;:&quot;http|www|yahoo|com&quot;}]}
```

The mistake by my side was that I used the `print_r` method instead of the  `var_dump` . This had as a result to print out the `&quot` as `"` in my page .

Comment: Wfm https://3v4l.org/mufMB

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? I tested it and it worked.

Comment: My `php -v` returns `PHP 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.1 (cli)`

Comment: where do you get `$json_string` ? is it in source code or from other source ? perhaps it is encoded (backslashes added ?)

Comment: The ones that down voted can explain the reason ?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but at a guess it was probably that the question was written in such a way the information provided didn't / doesn't match the error you were getting. As far as the rest of us are concerned, the json and the json_decode provided work perfectly well.

Comment: The guys downvoting should ask before downvote. Thanks @JonStirling for the answer and apreaciate. Definetely the problem still exists, and I don't know where it comes from. When I try single string it works, and when I use the variable doesn't :(

Comment: I found the issue, definetely the string was html encoded and when I used the `print_r` the `&quot;` was replaced by `"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json string is valid, and it works. You can add `true` for the second parameter of `json_decode`, and you get back an `array`.
Try the following:

```
$json_string = '{"values":[{"url":"http://www.google.com","matches":"http|www|google|com"},{"url":"http://www.yahoo.com","matches":"http|www|yahoo|com"}]}';

var_dump(json_decode($json_string, true));
```

It works for me.
[image]

Comment: Can you add what you've actually changed?

Comment: @JonStirling Setting true for json decode to make it associative and wrapping in single quotes.